# upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04 on dell latitude 430

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, dell

I can upgrade to a later version. The upgrade process stops before starts to get the packagings. Says 'network error' however the network works fine on the machine!?

HELP PLS!!

Comment: New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Comment: @EliahKagan, I remember you said something similar before. So we should answer (if we can) how to go from one EOL version to another EOL version, to ultimately get to a supported version. Should the FAQ be modified to make this clear?

Comment: @vasa1 If necessary, maybe. But the FAQ *doesn't imply this is off-topic.* We don't support Windows but we do support installing Ubuntu starting with Windows, even in Windows-specific ways. We also support Ubuntu *services* (see the FAQ) accessed in officially supported ways from other OSes, like Ubuntu One. So in addition to being *a way of installing Ubuntu*, upgrading an EoL release uses the `old-releases` server which is an Ubuntu-related service provided by Canonical. (I **don't** maintain that EoL upgrade questions that would *not* help someone get to a supported release are on-topic.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch Synaptic (it is the default package manager in 10.04) and check in Menu/Settings/Repositories that you are using the main server, and not a local server. Some mirrors keep only LTS and current Minor release, so 11.04 may not be available. Try this and let me know. If it doesn't work or if you want to install 12.04 directly, got to step 2 and 3.
2. Go to the "Updates" section of the windows, and check that "Notify me a new Ubuntu version" is set to "For long term support versions"
3. Close Synaptic, start the Update manager, click on check. Instead of suggesting an update to 11.04, it should suggest to upgrade to 12.04. Try this and again, let me know.